# How to get the Only success (200 ok) Response from Http Request Using Groovy script

Tags: http, groovy, response

Here i'm Facing problem with groovy script that.Want to extract the response data from the http request.When the Response data consisting of 200 as value then only extract that  value_description and print value. 
So here is the response what i am getting

```
{"value":"200","value_description":"pass"}
```

and code is

```
def response = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse("200".equals(prev.getResponseData()))
```

means is there any possible that  if value is 200 and than only print value description.using groovy script please tell me with simple code.

Comment: What do you have so far?  It's hard to say from the question which bit you're stuck on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you mean, it's really hard to tell, but I *think* you mean:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def response = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(prev.responseData)
if (response.value == '200') {
    println response.value_description
}
```